# How can i use Json array value in drop down list?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I trying to create notification module in my application. My qus is how can i use json array with for each in Ajax and append in drop down list

Here is my code-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
               url: "http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.2.0/index.php/admin/GetNotification",
                async: false, //<-- make it synchronous
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                    $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
                    alert( key + ": " + value );
                    });

                    }
                }); 
});

    </script>
```

This is my json array-

```
 [{"tid":"1","message":"Some on ping you","created_date":"2014-11-20 11:15:20.352631"},{"tid":"2","message":"Hello admin,Aniruddha mishra want to see Rahul patni profile","created_date":"2014-11-20 11:18:21.758673"}]
```

and i want use this value in this drop down -

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="noti" style="background-color:black">
   <li>/// here i want all value dynamically with for each  ///</li>
  </ul>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = [
  {"tid":"1","message":"Some on ping you","created_date":"2014-11-20 11:15:20.352631"},
  {"tid":"2","message":"Hello admin,Aniruddha mishra want to see Rahul patni profile","created_date":"2014-11-20 11:18:21.758673"}
];

#1
var $doc = $('<div />');

$.each(data, function () {
  $doc.append($('<li />').text(this.message));
});

$('#noti').html($doc.html());

#2
var menu = $.map(data, function (el) {
  return '<li>' + el.message + '</li>';
});

$('#noti').html(menu.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use JQuery append function. Using the ul tag id, append the li tags. Hope this works:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.2.0/index.php/admin/GetNotification",
            async: false, //<-- make it synchronous
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                var json=JSON.parse(response);
                $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
                    $("#noti").append('<li id="'+key+'">'+value+'</li>');
                });

            }
     }); 
});
```

Comment: hey i got this error 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '199' in

Comment: Now it is in string format, convert into json format, use JSON.parse.
var json=JSON.parse(response); Hope now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In success function:

```
 success: function(response, status, xhr) {
 var html = "";
 $.each(response, function(key, value) {
     html += "<li>";
     html += value.message;
     html += "</li>";
     //alert( key + ": " + value );
 });
 $("#noti").append(html);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/1cy803ar/5/

JS:

```
var data = [{
    "tid": "1",
        "message": "Some on ping you",
        "created_date": "2014-11-20 11:15:20.352631"
}, {
    "tid": "2",
        "message": "Hello admin,Aniruddha mishra want to see Rahul patni profile",
        "created_date": "2014-11-20 11:18:21.758673"
}]
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    li.attr({
        id: data[i]['tid'],
        date: data[i]['created_date']
    }).text(data[i]['message']);
    $('#noti').append(li)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On success Call this Function

function onSuccess(response)
{

var temp=" ";

var noti=document.getelementByID('noti');

if (response.d.length > 0 )
{

for (i=0;i

{

temp+  =  "<    li value=" response.d[i].message"> "+response.d[i].message +"    <  /li>"

}

}
$("#" +noti).append(temp);

}